# Table content outside of table

Tags: html, firefox

I have a table that looks like this in the source code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tc> (stuff) </tc>
        <tc> (stuff 2) </tc>
        <tc> (stuff 3) </tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc> (stuff 1) </tc>
        <tc> (stuff 2) </tc>
        <tc> (stuff 3) </tc>
    </tr>
    (etc)
    </tr>
    <tr>
        (more 'tc's)
    </tr>
```

Now, when I open this in firefox, it opens it like this:

```
<tb></tb>
    <tc>UID</tc>
    <tc>Username</tc>
    <tc>Password</tc>
    <tc>Groups</tc>
    <tc>Profile picture</tc>
    <tc>(uid taken out by me)</tc>
    <tc>administrator</tc>
    <tc>(password taken out by me)</tc>
    <tc>admin, member</tc>
    <tc>https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.495617734.2529/pp,550x550.u1.jpg</tc>
    <tc>(uid)</tc>
    <tc>(username)</tc>
    <tc>(password)</tc>
    <tc>admin, member</tc>
    <tc>https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.495617734.2529/pp,550x550.u1.jpg</tc>
    <tc>(uid)</tc>
    <tc>test member</tc>
    <tc>(password)</tc>
    <tc>member</tc>
    <tc>imgs/defaulticon.png</tc>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Please send help, as I have no idea what's going on.
The code is right;
The output is wrong.

Is this some kind of firefox bug,
or does firefox restructure code when it runs it?

Comment: `tc` is not a tag, read about html tables [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<tc>` (or `<tb>`) element in HTML. The browser is trying to recover from your error by moving the unknown element outside the table.

Write [valid HTML](https://validator.nu/). Read [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data).

A `<table>` contains `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>` and `<thead>`. The latter three of those contain **rows** (`<tr>`) which contain **heading** and **data** cells (`<th>` and `<td>`).

Comment: Thank you, my HTML book must have been wrong, or at least old.

Comment: There has *never* been a `<tc>` element in HTML.

Comment: Then I remembered it wrong, and  I feel slightly stupid.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use "td" instead of "tc" tag.